# How to form a nested structure of unique years, months and days?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of dates as follows:

```js
[
  "2020-06-20T11:18:40.359Z",
  "2020-06-15T11:17:45.511Z",
  "2020-05-13T11:19:45.511Z",
  "2019-04-20T11:49:27.828Z"
]
```

What can I do to get the following structure from my array?

```js
{
  2020: {
    5: [
      20, 15
    ],
    4: [
      13
    ]
  },
  2019: {
    3: [
      20
    ]
  }
}
```

I think it's worth noting that the initial array may contain thousands and even tens of thousands of dates and it updates every second.

Comment: By the way the structure you provided as the intended result is not correct, the years should be objects not arrays.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: months, date according to local timezone right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to categorize your data here, the best method is `reduce()` function of `array`. Inside reduce, we pass an empty object to `accumulator` to start grouping the data. We will then get `year`, `month` and `date` from the current iteration element. I have destructured those value here. The rest of the logic is pretty understandable from the code.

```js
var data=[ "2020-06-20T11:18:40.359Z", "2020-06-15T11:17:45.511Z", "2020-05-13T11:19:45.511Z", "2019-04-20T11:49:27.828Z"];

var result = data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
   const [year, month, day]  = [new Date(elem).getFullYear(), new Date(elem).getMonth(), new Date(elem).getDate()];
   acc[year] = acc[year] || {};
   acc[year][month] = [...(acc[year][month] || []), day];
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Maybe best to use `.getFullYear()` to account for dates close to new year's eve?

Comment: @thammada.ts, yes we can do that as well.

Comment: Great little script! But what is going on in this line?  
    ```acc[year][month] = [...(acc[year][month] || []), day];```  
Do you mind explaining?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. The current `month` and `day` are accumulated (but the `month` only if not present yet).